# Multiple Fonts in Multiple div

Tags: html, css

I have following code to use
Multiple Fonts in Multiple div
the fonts classes not work in side div

```
<style>

@font-face {font-family: 'Alharbi';src: url('/fonts/Alharbi.ttf');
@font-face {font-family: 'Tahoma';src: url('/fonts/Tahoma.ttf');
@font-face {font-family: 'Kufyan';src: url('/fonts/Kufyan.ttf');


.Alharbi{   font-family: 'Alharbi';}
.Tahoma{    font-family: 'Tahoma';}
.Kufyan{    font-family: 'Kufyan';}

</style>



<div  class="Alharbi  text-center" style="padding:10px;width:100%;height:40px;"  >Alharbi Font In this Div</div>

<div  class="Tahoma  text-center" style="padding:10px;width:100%;height:40px;"  >Tahoma Font In this Div</div>

<div  class="Kufyan  text-center" style="padding:10px;width:100%;height:40px;"  >Kufyan Font In this Div</div>
```

Comment: Not every browser supports TrueType fonts (.ttf)

Comment: it's firfox , and the code work when I use the font for all site , but error when I use multiple font for muliple div

Comment: My guess is: not all users will use Firefox..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must place a `}` on the end of the `@font-face` methods.